Why Doesn't My Code for Computing and Plotting Eigenvalues of a Discretized Hamiltonian Matrix Produce Any Output?
I've been working on a quantum mechanical model where I discretize the Hamiltonian using the finite difference method. My goal is to compute the eigenvalues and visualize them, but my code doesn't produce the expected results, such as eigenvalues and their corresponding plot. I'm using Mathematica, constructing the Hamiltonian matrix with a kinetic term and potential term, and solving it using the Eigenvalues function
Why does the following Mathematica code fail to generate the eigenvalues and corresponding plot, even though I’ve constructed the Hamiltonian matrix using the finite difference method and applied the Eigenvalues function to solve for the eigenvalues?
(* Step 1: Define Parameters *)
N = 1000; (* Number of grid points *)
xMin = 1; (* Minimum x value *)
xMax = 20; (* Maximum x value *)
y = 1; (* Arbitrary constant for potential *)
hbar = 1; (* Planck's constant, set to 1 for simplicity *)

(* Step 2: Grid Spacing and Potential *)
Δx = (xMax - xMin) / N;
xGrid = Table[xMin + i Δx, {i, 0, N - 1}];

(* Define Potential V(x) *)
V[x_] := y Exp[-(Log[x])^(1/4)];
VGrid = Table[V[x], {x, xGrid}];

(* Step 3: Construct the Hamiltonian Matrix *)
H = SparseArray[
   {Band[{1, 1}] -> -hbar^2/(2 Δx^2) + VGrid + xGrid/Log[xGrid],
    Band[{2, 1}] -> hbar^2/(2 Δx^2),
    Band[{1, 2}] -> hbar^2/(2 Δx^2)},
   {N, N}
];

(* Step 4: Compute Eigenvalues using Eigensystem *)
eigenvalues = Eigenvalues[H];

(* Step 5: Plot the Eigenvalues *)
ListPlot[eigenvalues, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Eigenvalue Index", "Eigenvalue"}, 
 PlotTitle -> "Eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian Matrix", 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]

Output:ListPlot[ArnoldiMethod[
  SparseArray[
   Band[{1, 1}] -> 
    0.08 E^(-2 Sqrt[-12 + e + Log[Range[1, N]]]) - (-1 + N)^2/19602 + 
     Range[1, N]/Log[Range[1, N]], Band[{2, 1}] -> (-1 + N)^2/19602, 
   Band[{1, 2}] -> (-1 + N)^2/19602, {N, N}], N], PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Eigenvalue Index", "Eigenvalue"}, 
 PlotTitle -> "Eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian Matrix", Joined -> True,
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic]

Output:\!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"ListLinePlot", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Transpose", "[", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"xMin", "+", 
RowBox[{"i", " ", "\[CapitalDelta]x"}]}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"i", ",", "0", ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "N"}]}], "}"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Normalize", "[", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], "}"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], "}"}]}], "}"}], "]"}]}], "}"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"PlotRange", "->", "All"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"PlotLabel", "->", "\<\"Wavefunction 1\"\>"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"AxesLabel", "->", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\<\"x\"\>", ",", "\<\"|\[Psi](x)|^2\"\>"}], "}"}]}]}], "]"}], 
RowBox[{"ListLinePlot", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Transpose", "[", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"Table", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"xMin", "+", 
RowBox[{"i", " ", "\[CapitalDelta]x"}]}], ",", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"i", ",", "0", ",", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "N"}]}], "}"}]}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"Normalize", "[", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"Abs", "[", 
RowBox[{"1", ";;", "5"}], "]"}], "2"], "]"}]}], "}"}], "]"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"PlotRange", "->", "All"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"PlotLabel", "->", "\<\"Wavefunction 2\"\>"}], ",", 
RowBox[{"AxesLabel", "->", 
RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"\<\"x\"\>", ",", "\<\"|\[Psi](x)|^2\"\>"}], "}"}]}]}], "]"}]}
},
AutoDelete->False,
GridBoxItemSize->{
     "Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}],
"Grid"]\)

What could be causing the issue, and how can I fix it to obtain the eigenvalues and a proper plot?

In addition to the issue of redefining N, since xMin is 1, Log[xGrid] will be undefined in the line containing Band[1,1] .  Also, for quicker results, use Eigenvalues[ H // N ] to calculate eigenvalues as approximate (floating point) numbers.

Please read the error message top to bottom. The first one is
Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected.

This means that you cannot assign to the symbol N. It is a built-in symbol and protected. (As several uppercase letters as C, D, E, I, K,... are. For this reason N is not set to 1000 for this reason. And thus, almost everything from thereon is meaningless.
Just replace N by any other symbol, e.g., pointcount. (Something like this might be more expressible anyways.)
